# jquery datapicker in partial view MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, partial-views

I use the bootstrap datapicker [(bootstrap datapicker)](http://runnable.com/UmOmQbKV4wpoAAGa/bootstrap-datepicker-example-date-range-from-to-with-%22today%22-button-activated2) and it works nice, but when i try use it in partial view didn't work. I use this in my view:

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>         $('#datepicker').datepicker();
> ```

And the same code in document ready in my partial, but didn't works...

The field datapicker:

```
>  <div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date="dateValue: Customer.DateOfBirth"
> data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
>                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InicioServ, new { @class = "form-control input-sm add-on", id = "InicioServ" })
>             </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the following jQuery in the base view, not the partial view

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () { 
          $(document).on('focus', '#datepicker', function () {
              $(this).datepicker();
          });
      });
</script>
```

This will work when a partial view is dynamically loaded and on page load.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are looking up by id and the dom only keeps one and ignores the second.

Add the datepicker by setting a class name as follows instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

...

```
<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker2" class="datepicker" data-date="dateValue: Customer.DateOfBirth"
 data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InicioServ, new { @class = "form-control input-sm add-on", id = "InicioServ" })
            </div>
```

I'd also give them different Id's to keep them separate or you may run into dom problems.

Comment: wrote badly in the post by distraction, is not the solution

Comment: my problem is not id's because I have different id's. I think it does not load the document ready in partial

Comment: Well this line here is loading against an Id?????  $('#datepicker').datepicker(); and it will only load the calendar with an id of datepicker, you need to load it against a class or have two id date picker calls.

Comment: Yes, i know, and to solv this i have:
`$(document).ready(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            $('#datepicker' + i + '').datepicker();
        }
});`

And:

`<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker1" data-date="dateValue: Customer.DateOfBirth" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                    <div class="right-inner-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor( ...)
                    </div>
                </div>`

Comment: Nice one, please accept and upvote my answer. I was correct, on second answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a [different DatePicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), check out [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Documentation/Plugins), using which you'd write something like this and it would just work:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(x => x.Date).DatePicker()
```